# Get input content in multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to show my input content in multiple places, but nothing happens when I put `getelementsbyclassname('output')` instead of `getElementById('output')`

I actually have this but because of the getElementById, only the first element is changing

```
<script>
function functionname() {
     document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=document.getElementById('input').value;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="functionname();return false;" />

<span id="output"></span>
```

Thanks by advance, and sorry for the bad english

Comment: If you tag a question as jQuery, you can expect jQuery answers. Was that intentional (as all your code is RAW JavaScript)?

Comment: I can see only one input/output element, show us proper markup

Comment: The current code is working. Why do you want to select by class name. `output` is an ID.

Comment: `getelementsbyclassname` is not a JS function.. `getElementsByClassName` is tho.

Comment: `getelementsbyclassname` wouldn't work as it's case sensitive. should be `getElementsByClassName`. you'd also have to loop through the elements... or just use jquery `$(".output").html($("#input").val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var spans = [].slice.call(document.querySelectAll('.output'));

var val = document.getElementById('input').value;

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
   spans[i].innerHTML = val;
}
```

This will work on spans with a class of `output`:

```
 <span class="output"></span>
 <span class="output"></span>
 <span class="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You have no element with a class of "output".
2. JavaScript is case-sensitive. `getelementsbyclassname` should be `getElementsByClassName`.

```html
<span class="output"></span>
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    outputs = document.getElementsByClassName('output')

for (i=0; i<outputs.length; i++)
    outputs[i].innerHTML = input.value;
```

However as you have [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tagged, you can instead use the following:

```
$('.output').html($('#input').val());
```

Comment: Also, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so to get the first one, you need `document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to update the html of multiple divs based on the value of an input

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div class="output"></div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.output').html($('#input').val());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DDnXs/